# Need to iframe to all screen sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Sorry for the lame question. I need to add code to get my iframe to be responsive to all screen sizes both height and width.

Can any one help, iframe code i have so far is below.

```
<iframe name="ROL_iframe" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="https://iframe.resales-online.com/weblink/inc/start.asp?P1=BritanniaBusinessSales" frameborder="NO" noresize width="1200" height="2300" align="center" onload="window.scroll(0,0)"></iframe>
```

Many Thanks

Matt

Comment: <iframe name="ROL_iframe" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="https://iframe.resales-online.com/weblink/inc/start.asp?P1=BritanniaBusinessSales" frameborder="NO" noresize width="1200" height="2300" align="center" onload="window.scroll(0,0)"></iframe>

Comment: <iframe name="ROL_iframe" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="https://iframe.resales-online.com/weblink/inc/start.asp?P1=BritanniaBusinessSales" frameborder="NO" noresize width="1200" height="2300" align="center" onload="window.scroll(0,0)"></iframe>

Comment: start here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_responsive_iframes.asp

And better to put code up in body of your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the Iframe a class and give it:

```
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
```

That should make it cover the screen.

Comment: 100vw = 100% Screen width
100vh = 100% Screen height